# websecurity.login returns true but not actually logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This project is developing with **asp.net mvc 5**. This code works correctly in other project. Other project is developed with **asp.net mvc 5** too.

the patient here:

```
if (WebSecurity.UserExists(userName))
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(userName, password))//this returns true
        {
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, SysRoles.Admin.ToString()))
            {
                LoginResultMessage msg = new LoginResultMessage();
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                model.isLoggedIn = false;
                msg.MessageType = LoginResultTypes.error.ToString();
                msg.Message = LangRes.RoleFail;
                model.messages.Add(msg);
            }
            else//continuing from here because role is admin
            {
                string x = User.Identity.Name;//x is emptystring
                model.isLoggedIn = true;
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
       }
       else{...}
    }
```

i got 'x' variable as empty string, it means there is no user which logged in. But 2milisecons ago the program told me `if (WebSecurity.Login(userName, password)) = true`. And redirecting same page(user not authenticated page = login page). I don't understand what's going on. Thanks for any help and sorry for english massacre:).

Comment: You are mistaken.  This code does not work in MVC4, because it's not possible for it to work in MVC4.

Comment: you are right very sorry, other project is mvc 5 too.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the code can't work in any version of MVC.  See the duplicate question link.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch i believe you or i belive my working codes?

Comment: It's impossible for it to work as you've written it.  I guarantee you, this is not working in your other project.  The other project must be doing something different.

Comment: Perhaps you'll believe Microsoft.  See the (remarks section) [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx ] `When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a cookie that lets ASP.NET know on subsequent requests that the user has been logged in.'

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you are right, I can't get `user.identity.name` like above, I just added there for example. I guess I wasn't clear enough, I mean this code work as well other project, I log in and page redirect which I specified url. But this one, I log in and page redirect again the same page. It means log in failed, but `if (WebSecurity.Login(userName, password))` told me true and codes are run this context then page reload, but User.Identity.Name returned `string.Empty` when after page reload

Comment: Are you sure returnUrl isn't pointing to the current page?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch yes, first i try '**/manage**' page, but redirect me '**/manageaccount/login?returnurl=/manage**', i try log in, code works and told me user is exists and user is in admin role and returnUrl is '**/manage**' then page reload but redirected again '**/manageaccount/login?returnurl=/manage**' :((

Comment: Have you cleared your cookies?  Many times these problems (particularly when using a non-persistent cookie, which is the default) are caused by an existing cookie that is overriding the in-memory one.

Comment: Yes, i cleared cookies too but still same problem. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Well, I suggest you ask a new question, with the real code that doesn't work, not the fake code above that can't possibly work.  Show both the login code, and the code you use actually use to verify the failure (besides the fact you redirect).  Obviously, you don't need to include code that doesn't get executed (like your non-admin code)

Comment: Why are you even using WebSecurity in MVC5 anyways?  MVC5 uses ASP.NET Identity going forward.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I did what you told the last(I used asp.net identity) and now everything is more properly working, thanks for help